# How do you hide your IP in chatzilla?

Tags: irc, chatzilla

I use firefox's chatzilla plugin for IRC,

Is there a way I could hide my IP so that people can't find it by issuing an irc whois command?

Comment: You cannot do that, use a proxy or VPN.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: That's not true. Most servers allow for host masking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a server-side setting. You can try the following to ask the server to hide your IP :

```
/mode yournick +x
```

Even if the server supports it, it can still be bypassed by using DCC. So rule of thumb : don't expect too much anonymity on IRC.